# Modifying java program comments to update javadoc

Tags: javadoc

So I have to modify a given dr.java program, and i'm supposed to modify the javadoc. But when i change the comments in the dr.java program, such as adding: 
/** HI
*/ 
This doesn't output on the actual javadoc html link that i click on.

I do save it everytime, and compile each file. Why does it not update on the javadoc html?

Comment: Are you just compiling the file, or are you actually generating the java docs? In most IDEs, you have to explicitly generate javadocs; they aren't updated by simply building the program.

Comment: Dr Java has a button on the toolbar to start the Javadoc wizard

Comment: ^the button is blocked, as in i can't click it.

Comment: @colonel: i am just compiling the file, and when i do make an entirely new program, the button to create javadoc for the documents is blocked (i can't click it)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help guys, i found out that i was missing the JDK and after downloading it the javadoc worked.

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs1110/2011fa/announcements.html#javadoc